# Django Model Relationships (how to change a relationship)

Tags: python, django, models

I am a Django newbie. I have a model list like below. In this example, I have friendlists and friendrequestlists having users, but I want to have users having friendslists and friendrequestlists. How should I modify this code:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group


class Word(models.Model):
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    #add_date = models.DateTimeField(default=str(datetime.now()), editable=False)
    turkish = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    english = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    visibility = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='2')  #0(only me), 1(friends), 2(groups), 3(everbody)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.english

    #def add_date_pretty(self):
    #    return self.add_date
    def summary(self):
        return self.definition[:50] + "..."


class GroupEx(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group)
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group.name

class GroupReqList(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group)
    member_request = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group.name

class UserEx(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    casel = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class FriendList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserEx)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.user.username

class FriendReqList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserEx)
    friend_requests = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.user.username
```

Comment: So you need a query to get users having friendslists and friendrequestlists ?

Comment: I am a newbie. Could you give me more details? I want to be able to get friendlist through usernames, but in this case, this is not possible.